# How to get SD card reader working Realtek Device 5287

Tags: 13.10, realtek, sd-card

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. The SD card reader is not working.`lspci` shows this:

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
```

I don't know what I changed but a month earlier it worked well...

Answer (score 1):

Now it works again with kernel 3.13.0-29-generic. I noticed that it used to work already in Precise Pangolin 12.04 with 3.11.0-20-generic. Also it did not work a couple of weeks ago in Trusty Tahr 14.04 with 3.13.0-27-generic.